# Function field and meromorphic functions on a Riemann surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, riemann-surfaces, meromorphic-functions

Let $(X,\mathcal O_X)$ be an **integral** regular curve  over $\mathbb C$.  It follows that $X$ is also a connected Riemann surface.

From the algebraic point of view we can define the function field of $X$ as $K(X)=\mathcal O_{X,\eta}$ (where $\eta$ is the generic point). On the other hand from the analytic point of view we have the sheaf of meromorphic functions $\mathcal M$ on $X$ (here we have the usual definition of meromorphic functions by holomorphic charts).

Now, as far as I understand the vague statement of Serre's GAGA, we should have that meromorphic functions are the same as elements of $K(X)$. Does it mean that $\mathcal M$ is the constant sheaf:
$$U\to K(X)\;?$$
Honestly this seems very strange to me and probably it is incredibly wrong. So, can you please explain the relation between $K(X)$ and the sheaf $\mathcal M$?

**Important remark (this originated my question):** I'm confused by the definition of the so called *sheaf of stalks of meromorphic functions* on $(X,\mathcal O_X)$, which is denoted by $\mathcal K_X$. You may find the definition of $\mathcal K_X$ for example on Liu's book (chap. 7). Since $X$ is integral one can show that $\mathcal K_X$ is the constant sheaf $K(X)$! So it seems that, at least in the algebraic setting, the sheaf of meromorphic functions is constant...

Comment: The sheaf of meromorphic functions and $K(X)$ coincide only if $X$ is compact. For example, if $X=\mathbb{C}$, $K(X)$ is just the set of rational functions on $X$. But, $e^z$ is a holomorphic function (and thus trivially meromorphic) on $X$, which is not a rational function.

Comment: Dear @Mohan,  the **sheaf** of meromorphic functions does not coincide with the sheaf of rational functions even on a compact Riemann surface: see my answer.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg, Of course you are right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

a) For every Riemann surface $X$ (compact or not) the **sheaf** $\mathcal {Rat}$ of rational functions is different from  the **sheaf** $\mathcal {M}$ of meromorphic functions.
More precisely for **every** strict open subset $U\subsetneq X$, we have $\mathcal {Rat}(U)\subsetneq \mathcal {M}(U)$.
This is already crystal clear on the simplest example in the world: for $U=\mathbb C\subsetneq \mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)=X$ obviously $e^z\in \mathcal {M}(U)\setminus \mathcal {Rat}(U)$.

b) The sheaf $\mathcal {Rat}$ is constant for every Riemann surface $X$ (compact or not)  while  the sheaf $\mathcal {M}$ is non-constant for every such $X$.
What GAGA says (but was known in the special case of Riemann surfaces before Serre's article) is that the set of **global sections** of these sheaves are equal in the case of a compact Riemann surface $X$: although $\mathcal {Rat}\subsetneq \mathcal {M}$, we nevertheless have $\mathcal {Rat}(X)= \mathcal {M}(X)$.

Comment: Hi Georges, I was wondering if I can clarify the definition of $\mathcal{R}at$ with you? I have also seen you use the notation $\text{Frac}(U)$. If $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, or a Riemann surface, or a complex manifold, am I correct in defining $\text{Frac}(U)$ as follows? That is, $\text{Frac}(U)$ is the set of all functions $\varphi$ such that there exists $f,g \in \mathcal{O}(U)$ (holomorphic on $U$) and we may write $\varphi = f/g$.

Comment: I have never used the notation $Frac (U)$. What makes sense is the notation $Frac (\mathcal O(U))$. It consists of quotients $f/g$, where $f,g \in \mathcal O(U)$ such that $g$ is not identically zero on any connected component of $U$. The ring $Frac (\mathcal O(U))$ is a field if and only if $U$ is connected. It is a deep theorem that for $U$ non-compact $\mathcal M(U)=Frac (\mathcal O(U))$.